# How do I get Angular working in an HTA running IE 9?

Tags: javascript, angular, internet-explorer-9, ecmascript-5, hta

I'm required to develop an [HTML application](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML_Application) (HTA) to solve a business problem.  I consider that using [Angular](https://angular.io/) under the hood would greatly ease development.

I've created a new Angular project via `ng new` and made some small changes (detailed below), but when I run the built HTA file, I get this error:

> Error: 'console' is undefined

and the page never loads in the HTA window.

The HTA uses IE 9 (the requirements of the app prevent use of a later browser version), so the app includes this meta tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9">
```

[Angular's documentation states that IE 9 is supported](https://angular.io/guide/browser-support) if I uncomment all of the necessary polyfills in `polyfills.ts`, which I've done:

```
/** IE9, IE10 and IE11 requires all of the following polyfills. **/
import 'core-js/es6/symbol';
import 'core-js/es6/object';
import 'core-js/es6/function';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-int';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-float';
import 'core-js/es6/number';
import 'core-js/es6/math';
import 'core-js/es6/string';
import 'core-js/es6/date';
import 'core-js/es6/array';
import 'core-js/es6/regexp';
import 'core-js/es6/map';
import 'core-js/es6/weak-map';
import 'core-js/es6/set';
```

I've renamed the included `index.html` file to `index.hta` and made the corresponding change in `.angular-cli.json`.

I've tried to put the following code directly into `polyfills.ts` to circumvent the missing `console`:

```
if (!window.console) console = {error: function() {}};
```

but then I can't build at all, because it doesn't like me redefining `console`:

```
ERROR in src/polyfills.ts(77,22): error TS2322: Type '{ error: () => void; }' is not assignable to type 'Console'.
  Property 'assert' is missing in type '{ error: () => void; }'.
```

Can anyone suggest a way forwards from here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by adding the following code under the `<app-root></app-root>` line in `index.hta`:

```
<script>
  // HTAs don't have a console.
  console = {};
</script>
```

I now get the “Welcome to app!” screen when I double-click the HTA file.

It seems that Angular's build process doesn't look as closely at JavaScript declared inside the main page.